# How to reference another objects property in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class, which is not present in the code behind, I have declared a property, say "Name". Now I want to access this property "Name" in the aspx page.

I know we can do that by creating another property or a string variable or a hidden field in the code behind page and setting the "Name" properties value to it and accessing this new property/variable/ hidden field using <%= %> in the aspx page.

But I don't want to go by the above approach.

So is there any other way.

Comment: Why do you not want to add a property to the code behind? How are you declaring the class in the code behind?

Comment: @Oded - My class is not present inside the code behind file.

Comment: But your code behind is using it? How? If not, how do you expect to be able to call anything on it?

Comment: @Oded - yes, i am using it in the code behind.

Comment: Then explain how? Is it a field? What accessibility?

Comment: @Oded - I am passing it as parameter to a function, by creating an object of the class, but i am not setting its value to any control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a property on your code behind which will hold a reference to your class:

```
public SomeClass MyClass 
{
    get
    {
        // return an instance of SomeClass here
        return new SomeClass();
    }
}
```

and then in the aspx page you could access this property:

```
<%= MyClass.SomeProperty %>
```

Comment: Is there any other way ? Without using another property.

Comment: You need an instance. You could directly create such instance in the ASPX page if you want. But without an instance you cannot access this class but only its static members.

Comment: Yes Darin I am aware of that i have to create an object to access it otherwise declare it as static to access it. Can i use expression builder to create an object in the aspx page ?

Comment: What do you mean by expression builder? You could use server side expressions in the ASPX page: `<script type="text/c#" runat="server">SomeClass instance = new SomeClass();</script>` and then you could use this instance: `<%= instance.SomeProperty %>`

Comment: Yes this is what i want. Can you sent me walkthrough link for this, will appreciate that. :)

Comment: What walkthrough link do you expect? What issues are you currently encountering with your code?